# Node.js application using Django Admin Interface

Tags: django, node.js, nginx

I would like to build a new application using node.js but it requires quite a bit of backend management that I would rather not have to build. I have some existing code in django and really like the built in Admin interface for handling the backend management.

Is it possible for me to use something like nginx to direct all traffic to my node.js application except when the url path starts with /admin in which case it would direct the traffic to django?

Alternatively is there something like the admin interface for any of the node.js frameworks for certain databases?

Thanks.

Comment: Databases have their own admin interface that's completely seperate from node.js. If you use couchdb or mongodb the database management system for those can be used side by side with node.js

Comment: Raynos ... Django admin interface adds a lot more though, it will build an easy to use website perfect for backend management of the site. Then you can focus on the customer facing aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

It might be easier to just put your django admin app on a subdomain, `django.example.com`.

I'm using Django admin interface with a legacy PHP application. I found out I could build a nicer admin in just a few hours, than the special built one. The frontend is still obviously using PHP and the old code, but I just swapped out the entire admin backend which is now run on django against the database.

It's very nice indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Node.js, you might want to look into [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/) which can redirect requests to different places based on the route. It's very easy to setup and runs very fast from my experience.