# Admin panel for Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It's been a while since I'm looking for a Node.js package to provide a clean (but customizable) admin interface to perform CRUD actions on a MongoDB database in a structured manner (allowing trusted users edit their data involving automatic form validation, considering relationships between models, etc).

It's true it can always be used 3rd party tools to achieve this purpose (like the [Django Admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121844/node-js-application-using-django-admin-interface) or [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/)).

But I was wondering if there's an already made solution out there running on top of Node.js.

Does anyone know a solution of this kind?

**Note** that I'm NOT looking for an interface to access databases, like phpmyadmin or mongoose-admin.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is the conceptual difference between Django Admin and mongoose-admin??

Comment: Well, as far as I've seen, mongoose-admin doesn't provide a simple way for building custom views, like Django Admin panel does.

Comment: See my very closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119913/a-good-tool-for-building-admin-content-management-interface-over-mongodb

Comment: there's no reason to force yourself to use NodeJS for everything. Django can use MongoDB and you will get *great* validation of data, something you do not get with MEAN.

Comment: You should take a look at Forest Admin: https://www.forestadmin.com
We build the first backend-agnostic admin panel available as a SaaS where we only host he UI (never the data, nor the backend code).

Comment: check out AdminBro: https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/admin-bro

Answer (score 17, accepted):

https://github.com/jedireza/drywall

This seems promising as a good start to an admin panel.

Comment: Although in an early stage, already looks quite promising indeed.

Comment: Library looks good but it does not have bulk delete options..

Comment: Strapi can also be a good solution for these needs.

Comment: The github now points to: https://jedireza.github.io/aqua/

Comment: And the new thing totally doesn't answer the question - its too generic.  Wheres an actual admin panel?

Comment: The "new" successor project Aqua has been deprecated and archived as well .. :-/

Answer (score 17):

Have a look on this link:

https://github.com/wearefractal/smog

... it is a straightforward tool to admin mongoDB from webUI.

it looks pretty good, and may be in near future User based management will be added, but you can extend this to support the features you need.

**UPDATE**

`smog` is no longer supported, instead have a look into [MongoTron](http://mongotron.io/)

Comment: Not active any more, last commit was 2 months ago.

Comment: Which is now 2 years ago...

Answer (score 12):

If your Node.js app exposes a RESTful API, [ng-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin) is a good solution.

Disclaimer: we built it.

Answer (score 9):

We've used http://keystonejs.com/ for creating admin UIs.

Comment: Keystone creates simultaniusly Mongoose models, Graphql queries and mutations, and AdminUI. Very customizable, well documented and active

Answer (score 4):

We are using Formage (https://github.com/Empeeric/formage) as an admin addon and so far it has worked well for our basic needs. It is a fork from Mongoose-admin.

Answer (score 4):

Check [penguin](https://github.com/etabits/node-penguin): a module that automatically generates administration pages based on your Mongoose models.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using https://npmjs.org/package/mongo-express if you're used to bootstrap you might enjoy it too.

Comment: Are you still using this, I am trying to use this with mongodb 3 so after updating the mongodb packages the only thing it does is show: 'Add auth details to config or turn on admin!'. Without the updated mongodb packages I can browse through the databases but when trying to insert it complains about the drivers not fit for the mongodb version. Either way; it's broken for mongodb 3

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [AllcountJS](http://allcountjs.com). It's actually not a admin UI tool but rather a framework for rapid business application development. It builds auto-generated UI (grids, forms, etc.) from domain model descriptions in JSON-like format. Provides built-in security and user management. Supports view customization and theming (see [extending docs](http://allcountjs.com/docs/server)). If you're already using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) in your application you could integrate them to run in single Node.js instance.